# Navigation Bar- Size in CSS

Tags: html, css

I am currently working on a website that uses this navigation bar.
[image: Navigation Bar]

I didn't include it in the picture for the sake of space, but the brown portion stretches to both edges of the page.  How can I stop this from happening?

This is my HTML within the page:

[image: Navigation Bar HTML]

And this is my CSS:

[image: Navigation Bar CSS]

Thank you!

Comment: I wonder if taking snapshots could be easier for you, rather than posting the code.

Comment: Why did you set a background-color on the `<ul>` element?

Answer (score 1):

```
#navbar {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

You can also add a width attribute to define exactly how wide you want it.

Answer (score 0):

this might help

```
width:400px;
margin:auto;
```

Comment: It might be helpful to add some commentary on how you arrived at this suggestion, to educate the original poster.